# Parse vector into correct types

Tags: rust

Is there a way to convert a `String` to some other type dynamically? I have a vector of values in the format `key:type:value` that I'd like to convert to key value pairs where the value has been converted to the correct type. In this case the types map as: `i=i64`, and `f=f64`.

So far I have this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let arr: Vec<String> = vec!["A:i:49".to_string(), "B:f:0.1374".to_string()];

    let tup: Vec<_> = arr
        .iter()
        .map(|s| s.split(":").collect::<Vec<&str>>())
        .collect();

    println!("Arr: {:#?}", arr);
    println!("Tup: {:?}", tup)
}

// Arr: [
//     "A:i:49",
//     "B:f:0.1374",
// ]
// Tup: [["A", "i", "49"], ["B", "f", "0.1374"]]
```

Looking to acheive something like:

```
[("A", 49), ("B", 0.1374)]
```

I've looked at generics/implementations but cannot work out what to do.

Note: any vec may have any key, so the next set could be `["A:i:99", "C:i:0"]`, types are limited to integers, floats, and strings.

Comment: You can create a wrapper type like enum to hold different possible types like i32, f64, String to represent your values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using Enum wrapper type

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Value {
    IntVal(i32),
    FloatVal(f64),
}


let tup: Vec<_> = arr
    .iter()
    .map(|s| {
        let mut values = s.split(":");
        let first_tk = values.next().unwrap();
        let second_tk = values.next().unwrap();
        let third_tk = values.next().unwrap();
        let value = match second_tk {
            "i" => Value::IntVal(FromStr::from_str(third_tk).expect("Invalid int")),
            "f" => Value::FloatVal(FromStr::from_str(third_tk).expect("invalid float")),
            _ => panic!("unexpected pattern {}", second_tk),
        };
        (first_tk, value)
    })
    .collect();
```

playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0e8ae249e91cb0055f09c9b1bd96ebde

> Note: You need to do proper error handling and current code just panics whenever it encounters unexpected value. You need to use [Result type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) for that. Also, you could explore [FromStr trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) to parse from string